# What's the value of tau?

Tags: education, irrational-numbers, pi, constants

I've seen $\tau$ on a title of a YouTube video and I need help knowing what the value is.  I'm serious.  I've never heard of the value.  So, what is it?  Also, is it rational or irrational (this part might be a bit off-topic, but I *do* know that $\pi$ is famous)?  I think it's irrational.  Just tell me what you think!  Also, I've seen in one of Wikipedia's articles that $\tau$ is pronounced as \taf\ in Greek.

Comment: Can you link the video?

Comment: I don't even remember!

Comment: Probably $\tau = 2\pi$. There's a fad about that, and some people would like to replace $\pi$ with $\tau/2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer's right, though it could also [refer to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau#Mathematics) to golden ratio, in some uses.

Comment: This $\tau$ thing is up there with the sum of positives being a negative number. Kill it now.

Comment: Also, $\tau$ is pronounced 'taff' in Greek, just as $\pi$ is pronounced 'pee' not 'pie. Add that to the manifesto :-).

Comment: I was right!  $\tau$ _is_ irrational!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tau\equiv\dfrac{C}{R}=2\pi$. See [tauday.com](http://tauday.com)
It is a symbol used by $\tau$ists that define $\tau$ to be the true circle constant.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that tau=3.1415926535897932... x 2=6.2831853071795865...?

Comment: Yes, also that link provides very helpful information about it.

Comment: Circumference over radius!

Comment: "The true circle constant." *sigh*

Comment: @PedroTamaroff "used by $\tau$ists to define..."

Comment: The site's a joke, and has nothing to do with [Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism), by the way.

Comment: It uses the Taoist symbol but is unrelated - that's a bad pun, and a sign that this site isn't too serious (I knew the names are different, by the way).

Comment: Have you not read its manifesto?

Comment: @HDE226868 The $\tau$ that can be spoken is not the true $\tau$.